# Resource aws_acm_certificate does not have attribute 'domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value'

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to create a set of verification records for my ACM certs using Terraform, and I'm running into a strange issue.

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  domain_name = "${element(var.domains, count.index)}"
  count = "${length(var.domains)}"

  validation_method = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cert-record" {
  name = "${element(aws_acm_certificate.cert.*.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name, count.index)}"
  type = "${element(aws_acm_certificate.cert.*.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type, count.index)}"
  zone_id = "${var.zone-id}"
  count = "${length(var.domains)}"
  ttl = 30

  records = [
    "${element(aws_acm_certificate.cert.*.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value, count.index)}"
  ]

  depends_on = [
    "aws_acm_certificate.cert"
  ]
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert-valid" {
  certificate_arn = "${element(aws_acm_certificate.cert.*.arn, count.index)}"
  count = "${length(var.domains)}"

  validation_record_fqdns = [
    "${element(aws_route53_record.cert-record.*.fqdn, count.index)}"
  ]

  depends_on = [
    "aws_route53_record.cert-record"
  ]
}
```

Whenever I run that, I get the following set of errors:

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error occurred:
    * module.swarm.module.certs.aws_route53_record.cert-record: 5 errors occurred:
    * module.swarm.module.certs.aws_route53_record.cert-record[0]: Resource 'aws_acm_certificate.cert' does not have attribute 'domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type' for variable 'aws_acm_certificate.cert.*.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type'
    * module.swarm.module.certs.aws_route53_record.cert-record[4]: Resource 'aws_acm_certificate.cert' does not have attribute 'domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value' for variable 'aws_acm_certificate.cert.*.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value'
    * module.swarm.module.certs.aws_route53_record.cert-record[3]: Resource 'aws_acm_certificate.cert' does not have attribute 'domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name' for variable 'aws_acm_certificate.cert.*.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name'
    * module.swarm.module.certs.aws_route53_record.cert-record[2]: Resource 'aws_acm_certificate.cert' does not have attribute 'domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type' for variable 'aws_acm_certificate.cert.*.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type'
    * module.swarm.module.certs.aws_route53_record.cert-record[1]: Resource 'aws_acm_certificate.cert' does not have attribute 'domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value' for variable 'aws_acm_certificate.cert.*.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value'
```

What's odd is that this is almost a carbon copy of the example in the docs, just modified to use the "count" attribute and iterate a list of hostnames automatically.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/acm_certificate_validation.html#dns-validation-with-route-53

Debug Notes:

```
$ ../terraform -v
Terraform v0.11.14
+ provider.aws v2.19.0
+ provider.postgresql v1.1.0
```

Comment: Did you create `aws_acm_certificate_validation` ?

Comment: @RyanKim, yes, I just neglected to include it in the snippet above. Added.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the same problem and don't think there is a solution:

1. You create a nested list when you add the count.  element, etc can't handle those nested variables as far as I can tell.
2. I moved mine into a module but hit the missing `count` for modules.

My final solution has been to create a module that does the above. Then call it multiple times.  Not ideal but it is clean.

Comment: I was able to solve this in version 0.12: https://gist.github.com/ksoviero-medici/1ff0738b856009ecd68ef4cf513688ff

Comment: Thanks @Soviero I'm moving to 0.12 so will give this a spin.